# Remove parent when child is removed cascade type

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I am having trouble figuring out the concept of cascading types. Let say I have two classes, User and Order. Some of the Users may have orders so that I have a reference to User in Orders.

**User:**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
}
```

**Order:**

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    private User owner;
    private int price;
}
```

**I want orders to be removed when corresponding user is removed. How to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Explanation of the cascading operations is on the bottom.*

Your question title "Remove parent when child is removed cascade type". It's not suggested that when you are removing the child, the parent is also removed. But if you want to have it you should modify the Order entity (unidirectional relationship because there is no orders reference in the User entity).

```
@Entity public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
or when only cascading for the removal @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) 
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User owner;
private int price;
```

Better is to change the entities. Some of the users may have orders. So i would add annotation @OneToMany to the User.

```
   @Entity
    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String phone;
        private String email;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
        private List<Order> orders
    }

@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private int price;
}
```

When there is no reference to the User in the Order entity (above code) it's called unidirectional relationship. You can add a reference in the Order making the relationship bidirectional.

A typical bidirectional relationship example:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="owner");
    private List<Orders> orders
}

@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User owner;
    private int price;
}
```

cascade CascadeType.ALL on the User @OneToMany relationship means that all operations on the User entity will be propagated to the Order entity. So when removing the User all the Orders frtom the property List "orders" will be also removed. You can define a few CascadeTypes. For example when having only CascadeType.REMOVE when you are removing the User, list of it's orders will be also removed but when you are saving the user the orders won't be saved. In most cases the CascadeType.ALL is popular and suggested on the @OneToMany side of the relationship.

If you need to read more about cascading DB operations  here is a link: 
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types.

For the bidirectional approach, what if I want only one order for each user?

A simplest way is to change the @OneToMany, @ManyToOne with @OneToOne on both sides. The default optional attribute for the @OneToOne relationship is true it means that the User don't need to have an Order. 
Other solutions may be to use a @MapsId annotation. There are also others. A best way of doing it depends on some criterias like do you have to have a bidirectional relationship or unidirectional is enough, if both entities must be set in the relationship, if you want to have lazy loading for @OneToOne.

Comment: For the bidirectional approach, what if I want only one order for each user?