# JPA unidirectional @ManyToOne relationship remove childs if parent is removed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class `A` and classes `B` and `C`:

```
public class A {
    @Id
    protected String name;
    ...
}

public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    ....
}

public class C {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    ....
}
```

If `A entity` is removed, I want all child entities to be removed too. I dont want a bidirectional relationship (in order to no have cycles between the classes and in order to not add more attributes to class `A`). Is that possible using `Hibernate` or have I to do this programatically in my service class?.

I guess if bidirectional relationship is needed for this I can write a parent class for `B` and `C` and use this parent class in a list to reference the childs in class `A`?

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409693/remove-parent-when-child-is-removed-cascade-type

Comment: Yes thank you @Turo !